# How do I write a bash script that sets up aliases for the parent shell?

Tags: bash, alias

I'm trying to write a script that will set up aliases for my bash shell, but I don't want to `source` it automatically in `.bashrc` - I need to have the aliases in a subset of my terminals.

Is it possible to `alias` a command in a script and have the aliased command work for the shell the script was run from?

Desired functionality:

```
$ alias
# ... no output here
$ ./my-script
$ alias
alias foo='bar'
alias alpha='beta'
...
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Aliases are private to the shells that they're created in. They can neither be exported, nor can they be accessed from a parent shell.

The easiest solution is to break the aliases out into a separate file, as you suggest, then either source that file by hand, or add a function to your `.bashrc`, that will source them when invoked.

```
function extra-aliases {
     . /path/to/file/containing/additional/aliases
}
```

Comment: Love it! Yeah, I'm keen to skip the `source /path/to/alias-file` and just have a single command - this will do the job. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

No. Aliases are private to the shell and subshells.

Answer (score 1):

No.

But to provide a 'solution', though I don't know if it's what you'd want.

Try:

```
# alias
... nothing
# . ./myscript.sh
# alias
alias ls='ls -laR'
```

Note the `.` before `./myscript.sh`. This is `source`.

Or why not make an alias out of it (in .bashrc):

```
alias mkalias="alias ls='ls -laR'; alias ll='ls -l'"
```

Comment: Thanks for the ideas, I hadn't thought of the second option. I like it!